# How to Rename Files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, file-rename

Is there a way to change name of a file in Android Studio projects? I come from Visual Studio and tried to select-change name of file. I already tried to <kbd>F2</kbd> thats keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Only the fact that Android Studio is special, so people must ask on StackOverflow how to do the simplest tasks, is somewhat ridiculous.

Answer (score 84):

- Select file in project explorer and press -> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- Select file with right click + Refactor -> Rename

Comment: You can change **Keymap** to eclipse in android studio. so you can use eclipse shortcut too.

Comment: @AhmetArslan Hey, you are right. How strange. I wonder if it's an updated version or I didn't do it correctly last time. I'll remove the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 13):

Find the file in the Project window:

Right-click >> Refactor >> **Rename File**

Comment: What's the difference between `Rename File` to `Rename`?

Comment: Any idea what is the difference.

Comment: I believe `Rename` searches for more usages including comments/strings, variables, text, and occurrences in tests while `Rename File` just searches for references and comments/strings

Answer (score 1):

If you have configure keymap as per "eclipse's keymap" than it will work.For change keymap , press Alt + Ctrl + S and change keymap from default to Eclipse Copy

Then below keys will work in android-studio :

```
1. Select particular file 
2. Press Alt + Shift + R
```

Now rename your file name.

Comment: Alt + Shift + R is shortcut for Eclipse, Android Studio is now based on IntelliJ with Shift - F6 for rename refactor

Comment: If you have configure keymap as per "eclipse's keymap" than it will work.For change keymap , press Alt + Ctrl + S and change keymap from default to Eclipse Copy .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes refactoring variables with refactor rename don't works in code.
Then we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (on PCs) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (On Macs)